# Adding a new card and deleting cards not working Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have a working subscription model that allows me to successfully have people signup as paying members. I'm trying to write an "edit page" that allows me to do the following

- add a new credit card
- delete card (which cancels the subscription)
- change the payment plan to another

Currently my page exists at /subscribe/edit with the following code

```
<%= form_tag do %>
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>


  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
  </div>

  <%= button_to "Add a New Card", :method => "updateSubscription" %>

<!--  <%= select_tag "type", options_for_select([['Subscriber' ,'Subscriber'], ['Sustainer', 'Sustainer']]) %>

  <%= button_to "Change Subscription", :method => "changeSubscription" %> -->

  <%= link_to "Delete Card and Subscription", :method => "deleteCard" , :confirm => "You sure?" %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  <!-- CURRENTLY USING TEST KEY -->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey("TESTKEY");

  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
      var $form = $(this);

      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

      Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

      // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });

  var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');

    if (response.error) {
      // Show the errors on the form
     $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
     $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
     // token contains id, last4, and card type
     var token = response.id;
     // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
     $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
     // and submit
     $form.get(0).submit();
    }
};  
</script>
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
  get 'subscribe' => 'subscribe#stepone'
  get 'subscribe/sliding-scale' => 'subscribe#steptwo'
  get 'subscribe/sliding-scale/subscriber' => 'subscribe#subscriber'
  get 'subscribe/sliding-scale/supporter' => 'subscribe#supporter'
  get 'subscribe/sliding-scale/sustainer' => 'subscribe#sustainer'
  post 'subscribe/sliding-scale/:type' => 'subscribe#createSubscription'
  get 'subscribe/edit' => 'subscribe#edit', :as => :edit_subscription
  post 'subscribe/edit'
  post 'subscribe/edit/deleteCard' 
  post 'subscribe/edit/updateSubscription'
  post 'subscribe/edit/changeSubscription'
```

and lastly here is my subscription controller

```
class SubscribeController < ApplicationController

  def stepone
  end

  def steptwo
  end

  def subscriber
    @type = "subscriber"
  end

  def supporter
    @type = "supporter"
  end

  def sustainer
    @type ="sustainer"
  end

  def createSubscription
    # Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    # See your keys here https://manage.stripe.com/account

    # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    token = params[:stripeToken]

    # Create a Customer
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
     :card => token,
     :plan => params[:type],
     :email => current_user[:email]
    )

    current_user[:stripeCustomerId] = customer[:id]
    # sets role of user, we should have a check for successful signu
    current_user.add_role params[:type] 
    current_user.save()

    UserMailer.subscription_confirmation(current_user).deliver

    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"


    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to root_url
  end

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def updateSubscription
    # Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    # See your keys here https://manage.stripe.com/account

    # Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    token = params[:stripeToken]

    # Create A New Card
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripeCustomerId)
    customer.cards.create(stripeToken)


    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Your Card Has Been Updated!"


    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to root_url
  end

  def changeSubscription
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripeCustomerId)
    @user.update_subscription(:plan => :type, :prorate => true)
    current_role = @user.roles.first.name
    @user.remove_role current_role
    current_user.add_role params[:type]
  end

  def deleteCard
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripeCustomerId)
    customer.cards.retrieve(customer.default_card).delete()
    current_role = @user.roles.first.name
    @user.remove_role current_role
  end

  def currentCard
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripeCustomerId)
    card = customer.cards.retrieve(customer.default_card)
  end

end
```

Currently if i click the "delete card" button i get the following in the url bar `http://localhost:3000/subscribe/edit?confirm=You+sure%3F&method=deleteCard` with no change in the page, same if i submit new card info.

Let me know what i'm doing wrong and how to correct my terrible ways :)

Answer (score 0):

The method option in `link_to` and `button_to` does not mean *controller* method.

It must be [one of five HTTP verbs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)  (get, post, put, patch, or delete) to use for the request when clicked.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", @obj, :method => :delete , :confirm => "Sure?" %>
```

Check out the Rails guide for [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for more in-depth guidance.

Also, **NEVER** use `button_to` inside of a form because `button_to` is itself a form. HTML spec forbids nested forms as it will cause unexpected problems up to and including small fires. To submit a form, use `submit_tag`.